# How can i send either an image or a video file using ACTION_SEND?

Tags: android, image, video, bitmap

I want to share either an image or a video file using `ACTION_SEND`.  So basically when the users taps on an image and selects "share image/video" it should send either the image selected or the video selected.

here is my code i am using:

```
if (filep != null) {

      }
      File sending=new File(filep);
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(sending),getMimeType(sending.getAbsolutePath()));
      intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, sending);
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Share"));
    }

  private String getMimeType(String url)
    {
        String parts[]=url.split("\\.");
        String extension=parts[parts.length-1];
        String type = null;
        if (extension != null) {
            MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        }
        return type;
```

So when testing, it takes me to which app i want to use to share with i.e whatsapp, Facebook, email etc.  And then when selecting either one, it then says "sharing failed, please try again."  I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work.  However i have the same code to display either image or video file full screen with `ACTION_VIEW` and that seems to work great but not with sharing.

Can anyone assist please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXTRA_STREAM` needs to be a `Uri`, and you are not passing a `Uri`. Use `Uri.fromFile()` to construct a `Uri`.

Also, replace `setDataAndType()` with `setType()`, as [`ACTION_SEND` does not use the data aspect of the `Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND).